# How to find and delete files using a bash script to read a text list of files

Tags: bash, unix, wildcard

This is likely a very easy fix but I haven't been able to find it so far... I have a bash script that reads through the lines of a text file. In that file there are partial file names (e.g. "l19s4"). I am trying to loop through all these partial file names and then, using wildcards in a find and remove command, delete all matching files.

I THINK the problem is with the wildcard/variable part of the code. I'm simply not finding the files. This script is being run inside the directory where the files all live. The text file reading and the loop work fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="filename1.txt"
while read -r line
do
    name=$line
    find . -name "*$name*" -exec rm -f {} \;
done < "$filename"
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you run the find commands manually, does it work? Try to put {} around ${name}.

Comment: Hmm, your code works for me. Can you break it down into smaller chunks to debug it? I wonder if there's an issue with what you're trying to match on your system since the code looks perfectly fine.

Comment: @alnet I am not sure how to exactly replicate the "*$name*" part (which I believe to be the problem) manually since it's intrinsically part of the loop. Running 'find . -name "*l19s4*" -exec rm -f {} \;' works fine.

Comment: Are the files all in the directory itself or are there sub-directories also?

Comment: Which lines/names are failing exactly? What are the matching files in the current directory?

Comment: Do you get any results if you just put: find . -name "*${name}*" ? Do you have permissions to delete the files?

Comment: @alnet: Tried the {} thing with no change in result. And I'm pretty sure it's not about permissions. I can't even get a result doing 'find . -name "*$name*" -print'. (strange: I see wildcards in my edit screen inside the quotes but they don't show up after I post)

Comment: @EtanReisner: No subdirectories. The files all look something like this "mtbs90-99_l8s608_chm.tif". I'd search on "*l8s608*".

Comment: Then you don't need `find` at all and can just use a normal glob. `rm -f *"$line"*` or `rm -f *_"$line"_*` or whatever.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I believe the issue is with using wildcards along with the $name variable. The find code SHOULD work, right? Even if it is unnecessary?. I have tried "\*$name*" and \*"$name"*.

Comment: Double quotes prevent the expansion of the `*` wildcard. Put them outside the quotes...

Comment: Have you tried using `set -x` at the top of the script and then review the output for clues to where/why it's failing?

Comment: New theory: this is about leading or trailing spaces (or some other garbage like that) in my text file.

Comment: @user3439894: Thanks. That set -x helped. Now I see that the variable was also storing the carriage return. I can probably figure out how to strip that out but will also happily accept suggestions that will be more elegant than my solution :)

Comment: Changed `name=$line` to `name=${line%??}` to strip of the "\r" and now it works. Apologies for the wild goose chase. Thanks, all.

Comment: One of your Tags is "unix" so where did the "filename1.txt" file come from that is has CRLF  (\r\n) (0D0A) line endings instead of just the Unix norm of LF (\n) (0A)?